# no matching function for call to `std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(std::string&)'

Tags: c++, string, ofstream

I am trying to write a program that ask the user for a file name and then it opens that file.  When I compile it I get the following error:

```
no matching function for call to std::basic_ofstream<char, 
std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(std::string&)
```

This is my code:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    string asegurado;
    cout << "Nombre a agregar: ";
    cin >> asegurado;

    ofstream entrada(asegurado,"");
    if (entrada.fail())
    {
        cout << "El archivo no se creo correctamente" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) can only be constructed with a `std::string` if you have C++11 or higher.  Typically that is done with `-std=c++11` (gcc, clang).  If you do not have access to c++11 then you can use the `c_str()` function of `std::string` to pass a `const char *` to the `ofstream` constructor.

Also as [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1294207/ben) has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35045920/4342498) you are using an empty string for the second parameter to the constructor.  The second parameter if proivided needs to be of the type `ios_base::openmode`.

With all this your code should be

```
ofstream entrada(asegurado); // C++11 or higher
```

or

```
ofstream entrada(asegurado.c_str());  // C++03 or below
```

I also suggest you read: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I dont think this is the case. It still fails for c++14 http://ideone.com/PVylpo, the problem is that there is no constructor that takes a string literal as the second argument.

Comment: Thank you so much! but where in the code will be the function `c_str()` ? I  never used it before.

Comment: @ben That is why I answered as I did.  I did point out the typo as well with attribution to you.

Comment: Ok, answers all scenarios +1.

Comment: I did it, i just added the function `c_str()` to `ofstream entrada(asegurado); and it works fine, now i'll read why is using namespace std;" considered bad practise. Thank you very much for everything! Grats

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor `ofstream entrada(asegurado,"");`, does not match that for [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream). The second argument needs to be a [`ios_base`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base), see below:

```
entrada ("example.bin", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
                            //^ These are ios_base arguments for opening in a specific mode.
```

To get your program running you simply need to remove the string literal from your `ofstream` constructor:

```
ofstream entrada(asegurado);
```

See the [live example here.](http://ideone.com/Uo3UVk)

If you are using `c++03` or lower then you cannot pass a `std::string` to the constructor of `ofstream` you will need to pass a c string:

```
ofstream entrada(asegurado.c_str());
```