# Can't use string in order name a file that i want to create

Tags: c++, string, file, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    ofstream file;
    string nameclass;
    cin>>nameclass;
    file.open(nameclass);
return 0;
}
```

```
The compiler says:
10  21  [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::open(std::string&)'
716 7   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\fstream [Note] void std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
716 7   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\fstream [Note] no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*'
```

Comment: This is an interesting piece of code and an interesting compiler message. But what is your *question*? Did you *understand* the error message? What did you think it was trying to tell you? What happened when you copied and pasted the interesting looking parts of it - like, say, `no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::string`, or `no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::open(std::string&)'` - into a search engine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no matching function for call to \`std::basic\_ofstream<char, std::char\_traits<char> >::basic\_ofstream(std::string&)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045781/no-matching-function-for-call-to-stdbasic-ofstreamchar-stdchar-traitscha) That was the first result for me when I [tried that](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=no+matching+function+for+call+to+%27std%3A%3Abasic_ofstream%3Cchar%3E%3A%3Aopen(std%3A%3Astring%26)%27).

Answer (score 1):

This is because, until [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), the function `std::ofstream::open()` is expecting a `const char *` instead of a `std::string`.
Fortunately, `std::string` already have a member function that converts the string into a `const char *` [`std::string::c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str).

Replace:

```
file.open(nameclass);
```

With:

```
file.open(nameclass.c_str());
```

And it should work :)

That being said, if you really want to pass a `std::string` directly, you will have to activate [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) support (at least) in your compilation options.

Comment: Maybe even better `ofstream file(nameclass);`.

Comment: @Alex This is the same issue :) OP seems to have a compiler prior to C++11 support.